# I am trying to fetch data from api and show in list or card view

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

`enter code here`#in extractedData data is fetched but i am getting an error saying I/flutter ( 7967): type '(dynamic, dynamic) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => dynamic' of 'f'
E/flutter ( 7967): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type '(dynamic, dynamic) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => dynamic' of 'f'
E/flutter ( 7967): #0      CategoryModels.fetchData (package:apiwork/models/category_model.dart:64:7)
E/flutter ( 7967):

```
  Future<void> fetchData() async{
    var url = "my api goes here..........";
    try{
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body);
      final List<CategoryModel> loadedProduct = [];
      if(extractedData == null){
        return;
      }
      extractedData.forEach((prodId,productData){
        loadedProduct.add(CategoryModel(
          id:productData['id'],
          image:productData['images'],
          name:productData['name'],
        ));
      });
      _cItems = loadedProduct;
      notifyListeners();
      print(_cItems);
    }catch(e){
      print(e);
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

#this is my home.dart

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  bool _selected =false;
  var _selectedIndex = 1;
  var _isInit = true;
  var _isLoading = false;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies(){
    // TODO: implement didChangeDependencies
    if(_isInit){
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });
      Provider.of<CategoryModels>(context).fetchData();
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    }
    _isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  void changeAnimatedContainerHeight(bool index){
    setState(() {
      _selected = index;
      _selected = !_selected;
      print(_selected);
    });
  }

  void onTapped(var index){
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }
  final List<String> imageList = [
    'https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.ayY5Ok1_cnPjwSRxEQERuwHaEO?pid=ImgDet&w=698&h=399&rs=1',
    'https://2qcolg3kl2ha3kfo912rzv2v-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/8/2017/01/food-1400x550.jpg',
    'https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.qIMnTRibgveVBeUXxEQwngHaE1?pid=ImgDet&w=1024&h=669&rs=1'
  ];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
      },

      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          leading: const Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined,color: Colors.black,),
          // title: const Text('Chitwan',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
          elevation: 0,
          actions: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 150.0,top: 5.0),
              child: DropdownButton(
                value:_selectedIndex,
                items:const [
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text("Chitwan"),
                    value: 1,
                  ),
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text("Kathmandu"),
                    value: 2,
                  ),
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text("Pokhara"),
                    value: 3,
                  ),
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text("Butwal"),
                    value: 4,
                  ),
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text("Hetauda"),
                    value: 5,
                  ),
                ],
                onChanged: onTapped,
              ),
            ),
            // PopupMenuButton(itemBuilder: (BuildContext context){
            //   return[
            //     PopupMenuItem(child: InkWell(
            //       onTap: (){},
            //       child: Text("Chitwan"),
            //     )
            //     ),
            //     PopupMenuItem(child: InkWell(
            //       onTap: (){},
            //       child: Text("Kathmandu"),
            //     )
            //     ),
            //     PopupMenuItem(child: InkWell(
            //       onTap: (){},
            //       child: Text("Pokhara"),
            //     )
            //     ),
            //     PopupMenuItem(child: InkWell(
            //       onTap: (){},
            //       child: Text("Butwal"),
            //     )
            //     ),
            //     PopupMenuItem(child: InkWell(
            //       onTap: (){},
            //       child: Text("Hetauda"),
            //     )
            //     ),
            //   ];
            // }),
            IconButton(onPressed: (){
              Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context,listen: false).logout(context);
            }, icon: const Icon(Icons.person,color: Colors.black,)),
            IconButton(onPressed: (){}, icon: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart_outlined,color: Colors.black,)),
          ],
        ),
        // drawer: AppDrawer(),
        // body:BottomNavigation()
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: Column(
              children: [
                Form(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:2.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 45.0,
                      width: 380.0,
                      decoration:const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color(0xFFF2F3F7),
                      ),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                            ),
                            icon: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                              child: Icon(Icons.search),
                            ),
                            hintText:'Hi, how can i help you?',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0)
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                // const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                AnimatedContainer(
                  height:_selected?220:140,
                  decoration:const BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(40.0),bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0)),
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  duration:  const Duration(seconds: 1),
                  curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      const Expanded(
                        child: SizedBox(
                          height:100.0,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                            child: CategoryGrid(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      IconButton(onPressed:(){
                        changeAnimatedContainerHeight(_selected);
                      },  icon:Icon(_selected?Icons.expand_less:Icons.expand_more),color:Colors.black12,iconSize: 30.0,),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10.0),

                CarouselSlider(
                  items:imageList.map((e) =>ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    child: Stack(
                      fit: StackFit.expand,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                          child: Image.network(e,fit: BoxFit.cover),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ) ).toList()
                  , options: CarouselOptions(viewportFraction: 1,height: 140.0,autoPlay: true,autoPlayAnimationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),),),

                const SizedBox(height: 10.0),

                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children:[
                    const Padding(
                      padding:EdgeInsets.only(right: 0.0),
                      child: Text("Today's Special",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 170.0),
                      child: GestureDetector(onTap: (){},child: const Text("More",style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFE10A35),fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),)),
                    ),
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                      child: Icon(Icons.chevron_right,color: Color(0xFFE10A35),),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),

                const SizedBox(height: 10.0),

                Row(
                  children: const [
                    Expanded(
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height:150.0,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
                          child:TodaySpecialGrid(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),

                const SizedBox(height: 10.0),

                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children:[
                    const Padding(
                      padding:EdgeInsets.only(right: 0.0),
                      child: Text("Our Partners",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 170.0),
                      child: GestureDetector(onTap: (){},child: const Text("More",style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFE10A35),fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),)),
                    ),
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                      child: Icon(Icons.chevron_right,color: Color(0xFFE10A35),),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),

                const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                Row(
                  children: const [
                    Expanded(
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height:180.0,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                          child:OurPartnersGrid(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),


                const SizedBox(height: 10.0),

                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children:[
                    const Padding(
                      padding:EdgeInsets.only(right: 0.0),
                      child: Text("Our Hotels",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 170.0),
                      child: GestureDetector(onTap: (){},child: const Text("More",style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFE10A35),fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),)),
                    ),
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                      child: Icon(Icons.chevron_right,color: Color(0xFFE10A35),),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),

                const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                Row(
                  children: const [
                    Expanded(
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height:180.0,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                          child:OurHotelGrid(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),

                const SizedBox(height: 10.0),

                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children:[
                    const Padding(
                      padding:EdgeInsets.only(right: 0.0),
                      child: Text("New Products",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 170.0),
                      child: GestureDetector(onTap: (){},child: const Text("More",style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFE10A35),fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),)),
                    ),
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                      child: Icon(Icons.chevron_right,color: Color(0xFFE10A35),),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),

                const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                Row(
                  children: const [
                    Expanded(
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height:180.0,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                          child:NewProductGrid(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),

                const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children:[
                    const Padding(
                      padding:EdgeInsets.only(right: 0.0),
                      child: Text("Vegetables",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 170.0),
                      child: GestureDetector(onTap: (){},child: const Text("More",style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFE10A35),fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),)),
                    ),
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                      child: Icon(Icons.chevron_right,color: Color(0xFFE10A35),),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),

                const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                Row(
                  children: const [
                    Expanded(
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height:500.0,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                          child:VegetableGrid(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                // const BottomNavigation()
              ]),
        ),

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think your problem is that json.decode returns a dynamic object, and you are trying yo use it in the forEach with key, value pairs. Try iterating differently on the object (maybe a normal for loop) and see if it helps.

Comment: actually i made two model main model is in another place which i made using quicktype and this categorymodel i made it myself according to the requirment on what to show on screen by fetching data from api and i tried different method but didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might fix your issue:

```
  extractedData.forEach((element){
    loadedProduct.add(CategoryModel(
      id:element['id'],
      image:element!['images'],
      name:element['name'],
    ));
```

Let me know if you have any more issues.

Comment: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Image>?' got this error

Comment: In this line?       image:element['images'],

Comment: yes i think so from my api data image comes as images

Comment: I think its a null check issue, I will modify the code above to check for nulls

Comment: the above answer worked but my image is not loading

Comment: in my api i have Image? image and i have different Image class and inside it there is src where image is loaded